# async await with Express : unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, async-await

I'm trying to use async/await with Express routes. But I still have an error

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

I tried a lot of things from StackOverflow or the web and nothing changes.

Here, what I did,

```
function asyncWrap(fn) {
  return (req, res, next) => {
    fn(req, res, next).catch(next);
  };
}
app.get('/user/:id', asyncWrap(async function(req, res) {
    //some stuffs
    try{
        const hor = await horaire(results[0].id, 2018, null);
    }catch(err){
        return err;
    }
}));

async function horaire(id, year, dateSpec){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject)  {
        let h=0;
        let days;
        if(dateSpec == null){
             days = moment(new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)).diff("2018-01-01", "days");
        }
        else {
            days = dateSpec;
        }
        let query =,
        query2 =;
        mysql.query(query, [id, year], function(error, result){
            if(error) console.log(error);
            else{
                if(result[0].days.length < days) console.log("Error : not enought date");
                else{
                    if((result[0].days.charAt(days))=='H'){
                        h = 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        mysql.query(query2, [id, h], function(error, result){
            if(error) {
                return error;
            }
            else{
                switch (new Date().getDay()) {

                }
                let array = [];
                array.push(hours(result[0].one));
                array.push(hours(result[0].two));
                array.push(hours(result[0].three));
                array.push(hours(result[0].four));
                array.push(hours(result[0].five));
                array.push(hours(result[0].six));
                array.push(hours(result[0].seven));

                arr = {day: day, horai: array};
                return arr;
            }
        });
    });

    return arr;
}
```

What did I miss ?

I use Express 4.16.2 and Node.js 8.9.4

Comment: Knowing what `some stuff` is could be useful

Comment: Where exactly do you get the error? And does the `// some stuff` include a nesting function?

Comment: typo: ```app.get('/user/:id,``` missing _'_

Comment: Thx for your comment. It's really long. But I call it in a mysql.query. And in horaire, there are mysql.query too. Separately, horaire works fine. But in the routes, the result is undefined. With async/await, I got unexpected identifier.

Comment: Thx @Unlockedluca , but the typo is not present in my code.
@Bergi I got the error with `await horaire(...);` where horaire is targeted. Yes, horaire includes others function.

Comment: When I surround the content in horaire with `return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){...});' I get this error `(node:1251) MaxListenersExceededWarning: Possible EventEmitter memory leak detected. 11 exit listeners added. Use emitter.setMaxListeners() to increase limit`. Thus, I tried `require('events').EventEmitter.defaultMaxListeners = 100;` But nothing changed.

Comment: @phenric Post your actual code, even if it's long, we're not able to help you otherwise. Of course, you may cut down on irrelevant stuff that doesn't affect the error message - but we need a [mcve] nonetheless

Comment: I edited with more codes. :)

Comment: what is  ```let query =,
        ```query2 =;

Comment: Some SELECT queries for MySQL represented as String.

Comment: Nobody can help me ?

Answer (score 0):

you have a typo in this function

```
app.get('/user/:id, asyncWrap(async function(req, res) {
    //some stuffs
    try{
        const hor = await horaire(results[0].id, 2018, null);
    }catch(err){
        return err;
    }
}));
```

checkout the missing '

```
app.get('/user/:id',
```

Comment: Thx for your answer but the typo is not present in my code.